# How do I resolve the url timeout error when running a yum command?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum

I'm trying to upgrade SVN 1.6 to 1.8. When I run the commands:

```
yum install mod_dav_svn subversion
```

I get the following error (after a short pause):

```
http://repo.andrewfarley.com/centos/5/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout: <urlopen error timed out>
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: andrewfarley. Please verify its path and try again
```

Of course going to that url does, indeed, timeout.

I've tried running these commands:

```
yum clean all
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
rpm --rebuilddb
```

However, the issues persist.

Comment: If I try that address in a browser, I get "Address not available."  As a hunch, I would say that repo no longer exists.

Comment: To add: Pinging 209.237.233.80 4 Packets Sent/4 Lost.  That repo is down and out....

Comment: Dead repo. That's a non-standard repo that someone used to get some of your packages. I'd determine what's coming from that repo and disable it in the `/etc/yum.repo.d/*` `.repo` files for it.

Comment: Surely, after doing as slm suggests, you can find replacement repos that provide the same packages for all the ones that were in the dead repo.

Answer (score 2):

Dead repo. That's a non-standard repo that someone used to get some of your packages. I'd determine what's coming from that repo and disable it in the `/etc/yum.repo.d/*` `.repo` files for it. You can determine which packages came from this repo if you know its shortname.

#### Example

Say this was in the `.repo` file associated with that repo.

```
[fedora]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch
failovermethod=priority
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$releasever-$basearch
skip_if_unavailable=False
```

The shortname is the string in between the square brackets, `[fedora]`. So you can check like this:

```
$ yum list installed | grep '@fedora'
ORBit2.x86_64                2.14.19-9.fc20         @fedora                     
OpenEXR-libs.x86_64          1.7.1-6.fc20           @fedora                     
PyPAM.x86_64                 0.5.0-18.fc20          @fedora
```

If nothing comes back then none of you packages are using this repo. In either case you'll need to deal with these packages either my upgrading them to newer ones from a newer repo or removing them.

#### New repo

Here's a repo that you can use for either 5 or 6 CentOS that provides SVN 1.8 + all the ancillary packages.

- http://tecadmin.net/install-subversion-1-8-on-centos-rhel/

Here's the x86_64 architecture of that repo that you can confirm definitely has the 1.8 mod_dav_svn package:

- http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/5/svn-1.8/RPMS/x86_64/

Comment: running sudo vi /etc/yum.repo.d/* .repo shows an empty file...

Comment: I went to the `vi /etc/yum.repo.d/` directory and have multple `*.repo` files: "andrewfarley.com.repo, CentOS-Debuginfo.repo,  CentOS-Vault.repo,  epel-testing.repo,   remi.repo,      utterramblings.repo,
CentOS-Base.repo,       CentOS-Media.repo,      epel.repo,   rpmforge.repo"

Comment: can I replace the url in the `andrewfarley.com.rep` with "http://tecadmin.net/install-subversion-1-8-on-centos-rhel/"?

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way. Just make a new `.repo` file and set that one to disabled.

Comment: I'm new and taking over a already setup repo, where can I go learn how to "make a new .repo, disable the current one, and point it to the new one"?

Comment: The link I gave you has the contents of the file you need to create for the new repo. Just make a file in that directory w/ an approp. name. To disable a repo, add the line `enabled=0`. It's a good practice to leave the repos in place until you've completely disconnected them, then delete. That way other ppl understand the lineage of where pkgs came from.

Comment: ok, disabled `andrewfarley`, created a new `.repo` you suggested, and now I'm running 1.8. When I tried to start Apache I get the following error: "Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 242 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so: undefined symbol: dav_register_provider"

Comment: I've checked and `/etc/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so` does exist

Comment: I found the `httpd.conf` file and these lines were commented out: "LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so, 
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so" I uncommented them and Apache was able to start. Of course now my SVN repos can't be checked out now... lovely

Answer (score 2):

From my side, there was an http proxy set in /etc/yum.conf. So removing it solved my problem.

Comment: Same here! Thanks!